# Why was sticky key introduced?

Tags: windows

When we press <kbd>Shift</kbd> many times a pop up comes if sticky key should be activated.. Whats the use of it?

Comment: You can turn this feature off if you want. For XP (http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/stickykeys.aspx) and for Windows 7 (http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/zanswers/2527)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabled people who cannot hold down two keys simultaneously. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>, hit your key, boom! Just like hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+key, but could be operated with a stick from your mouth. Or one finger.

Answer (score 3):

It's an accessibility feature for people who can't use two hands at once. For example, those with no arms, or immobile arms have to type using a single stick in their mouth.